# Would animated +1 daggers' attacks be considered magical?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, weapons

The Animate Object spells allows you to animate up to 10 tiny objects when cast at 5th level. In the case where the DM allows to bypass the restriction on nonmagical items, and if these objects happened to be +1 daggers (I know most characters do not have 10 +1 daggers, but for the sake of the argument let's say they do), would the damage from their attacks be considered magical for purposes of bypassing damage resistance, since when wielded by a character their damage is considered to be magical?

As a bonus, would the +1 to hit and the +1 to damage also apply to them while animated by the spell?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> Choose up to ten ***nonmagical*** objects... PHB page 213

Is the exact verbiage so by RAW you cannot do this with that spell.

That being said, should your DM allow it, I don't see a difference from a PC wielding a +1 Dagger or a spell wielding it to be perfectly honest, since it is the item itself granting that bonus.